Gabbai to not-so-good Torah reader
I was gabbai-ing as a guest in a relative's shul.  The Ba'al korei—who I was told reads regularly—made multiple mistakes in each verse.
What should one do in this case? Chop up the reading by correcting everything that changed the meaning (his errors included ones altering verb tenses and vowel switches that turned one word into another)?  Or correct only "howlers" and let many things go?
Thanks for your thoughts,
Chaim

Welcome to Mi Yodeya Chaim. Great to have you learning with us! Thank you for your first question.  Do take a look at this material about Mi Yodeya https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887

This is one where there's what it says on the books ... and then what happens in reality sometimes/some places ...

Also sometimes by the time I figure out if a trop mistake changes the meaning or not he's a few pesukim later

Snarky answer: A good Gabbai preempts the mistakes and prompts the reader a split second before he sings the words. (Usually requires a Ba'al Koreh as Gabbai)
